# OrderByDescending throws a SqlNullValueException

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

OrderByDescending with FirstOrDefault throws a SqlNullValueException but Orderby works well. I order by "Id" and Id is not nullable int.

If I use a where condition(t=>t.Stock) then OrderbyDescending it works, I tried with First instead or FirstOrDefault, same issue.

```
Yarn yFind = _context.Yarns.OrderByDescending(y => y.Id).FirstOrDefault();    // throw null exception  
Yarn yFind = _context.Yarns.OrderBy(y => y.Id).FirstOrDefault();  //working      
Yarn yFind = _context.Yarns.Where(y => y.Stock ).OrderByDescending(y => y.Id).FirstOrDefault();//working
```

Comment: Can you share the exception's stack trace?

Comment: Does it say `Yarns` is `null`, or `_context`?

Comment: Error :System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: 'Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.'  context is not null

Comment: @user3169539 NRE and `SqlNullValueException` are different exceptions… Please [edit] post with exact error message (and preferably [MCVE])

Comment: If I use an other field on OrderbyDescending it works Yarn yFind = _context.Yarns.OrderByDescending(y => y.ColorId).FirstOrDefault()

Comment: I get an error only If I sort the key(Id) and If use OrderByDescending, other field string/int doesn't throw an error.

Comment: We still need a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Damn I just figured out...
The last record(order by id) had a null boolean value on a field but NOT on model(entity)
so it can't convert null bit value to boolean.